# What is the sum of these numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this series:
$$A=1×\frac{n}{2^0}+2×\frac{n}{2^1}+...+k×\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}$$
How can I calculate $A$?

I know that the answer must be $2n$. But I do not remember how I did it then!

Thanks.

Comment: The finite sum cannot possibly converge to $2n$ for all $k$.

Comment: Assuming you mean the infinite sum, this should converge to 4n!

Comment: @Mathster yes the 2n is most probably wrong. anyway let me know what you think of my solution for any value of k using differentiation. Your limit approach looks great as well.

Comment: Haha, I honestly prefer your method to mine

Comment: Thanks all! It helped me find out my problem!

Comment: @Mathster Your method has it's merits though, but be mindful of the power of differentiating series like these. You know how we try to evaluate difficult sums by converting to integrals? There have been times I have done the opposite because of this. I read in some book on computer algorithms. "Introduction to algorithms" I think

Comment: That is a great technique! I'll keep it in mind. And +1 to you too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$S =1×\frac{1}{2^0}+2×\frac{1}{2^1}+...+k×\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} $$

If we can find $S$ , we only need to multiply by $n$ to get $A$.

Let $f(x) = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^k = \large \frac{x^{k+1}- 1} {x - 1} $

By the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Now differentiate both sides, the left side term by term, and the right side using the chain rule. Substitute $x=\frac12$ and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe $A=4n$, not $2n$.

Factor out $n$. So then you have $$A=n(\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{2}{2^1}+...+\frac{k}{2^{k-1}})$$
The inside is equal to $4$ because

[image] and we simply distribute the $2^{n-1} $and  take the limit as $n$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=1×\frac{n}{2^0}+2×\frac{n}{2^1}+...+k×\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}$$

Take n out

$$\frac{A}{n} = 1×\frac{1}{2^0}+2×\frac{2}{2^1}+...+k×\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

$$S = 1×\frac{1}{2^0}+2×\frac{1}{2^1}+3×\frac{1}{2^2}+4×\frac{1}{2^3}...+k×\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$
$$\frac{S}{2} = 1×\frac{1}{2^1}+2×\frac{1}{2^2}+3×\frac{1}{2^3}+4×\frac{1}{2^4}...+k-1×\frac{2}{2^{k-1}}+k×\frac{1}{2^{k}}$$

Subtract the last two expressions

$$\frac{S}{2} = 1+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}-k*\frac{1}{2^k}$$

$$\frac{S}{2} = \dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{2^k})}{\frac{1}{2}} - k*\frac{1}{2^k}$$

Replacing k with n, you get the following expression.

$$\frac{A}{n}= 4 - \frac{n+2}{2^{n-1}} $$
$$A = 4n - \frac{n(n+2)}{2^{n-1}}$$